# UDID registration

Tags: ios, ipad, replace, udid

If I replace a troubling iPad at the apple store will the UDID registration still count against my limit of 99 devices?

Comment: As much as this is a good question, it doesn't really belong on SO as it's not programming related.

Comment: Sorry it's just stackoverflow gets quicker responses and better than apple developer forms. Do you know the answer?

Comment: No I don't know, sorry. If you need the slot back immediately and notice it's being counted against you, you *might* be able to convince someone at Apple to restore it for you though?

Comment: @IsaiahTurner, Just because stackoverflow gets quicker responses than somewhere else it doesn't mean it's ok to post questions that are off topic. If anything, apple.stackexchange.com *might* be a better bet for this question - check out their FAQ to be certain before you ask there though! =)

Comment: This question is not off topic as device UUID registration is provided by the Apple Developer portal which falls under "software tools commonly used by programmers;" and it is also "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you will get your +1 value for registered devices back after 1 year.